# Code needed for htaccess redirect in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been fixing a strange htaccess issue on my client's WP sites.  I found a solution by putting the ReWrite code in the htaccess of each site and then adding a custom permalink code in permalinks and it seems to work EXCEPT for one section.

There are a total of 9 sites with this issue.  All of them have a highlights plugin on the front page that's pulling story and images and displaying them on the home page and then a link that goes to the story full page.  For my above permalink fix, out of the 9 sites, my fix works on 5 of them but on 4 of them in the highlights section, when you click a link I'm getting a 404.

The strange thing is, with my above fix, the highlight page still publishes, but not with my fix.  For example, when you click the "fixed" link it should open as:

mysite.com/central/index.php/highlights/my-page

...but I get a 404.  But all I have to do is delete the "index.php" in the above, and the page itself still works:

mysite.com/central/highlights/my-page

So what I now will do is write re-write code and put it in the root htaccess file so that when the page:

mysite.com/central/index.php/highlights/my-page

...is called it will re-write to:

mysite.com/central/highlights/my-page

...and that should fix this pesky issue.  Here's the catch - I'm not good at writing code and I used my own hosting company's re-write generator to create a sample for me to see but I can't use it to generate what I need because it only generates for my domain.  Since I don't know how to post code to this forum, below is a snap shot of it:

http://designerandpublisher.com/images/rewite-code.jpg

Is there a place where I can just copy and paste the URLs and it will generate the code so it looks like the above snap shot?  Or is there some kind of tutorial of what / and \ and  dollar signs and the periods and why they're there?  I used to set up redirect code a lot simpler than this but it seems more complex now and i'm just hoping there's some kind of generator?  Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following rule should work:

```
RewriteRule ^central/index.php/(.*) /central/$1 [R=302]
```

it should turn `mysite.com/central/index.php/highlights/my-page` to  `mysite.com/central/highlights/my-page`

(Change `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect works)